# Single Authentication between Controller and API ControllerBase in aspnet core 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an angular SPA asp.net core 3.0 application (default template with individual authentication).

When I'm logged in, the angular App and the `Areas/Identity` pages show that I'm logged in. when I go inside controllers and views, then the application shows that I have to login or register.

How to authenticate Controller request the same way as ControllerBase requests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, two weeks later. Just added these two lines of code

```
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
```

to set the default authentication scheme to "Identity.Application" instead of `"Cookie"`.

So, Initial code

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

was changed to

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        }).AddIdentityServerJwt();
```